# PHP user authentication with single-use tokens?

Tags: php, security

I'm writing user authentication for my php application. Please criticize my approach:

1. On successful login I do session_regenerate_id() and save the new session_id, user_id and expiry time in a db table. I also delete any old sessions for that user.
2. Each link or form action url in the response includes something like token=jenjdf723jhfej (the saved session_id).
3. Each request is checked against the sessions saved in the db. If the token matches a valid session a new session_id is generated and the db updated, if not, include the login form and exit. So a token is only valid for 1 request.

Is this approach safe?

I thought about adding the request ip address to the db as an additional check.

I'm open to using an existing auth system if you can recommend a good one.

Thanks

**Edit:** I've actually decided to do away with the token and just store a list of valid sessions, with their php session id and some other info, in a database table. Requests can still be checked against the table to confirm that a) the session hasn't expired and b) the request came from the same ip address that the user logged in with.

I might add a single-use token in the future. In which case I will probably generate it with something like `$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));`

This may mean that this question is no longer valid but thanks for your comments anyway. Mods/janitors, do with this question what you will.

Comment: You can add an extra layer, using stores procedures on your DB....btw , https defenders are coming ....

Comment: If you involve a hashed code in the response instead of the session id  use a salt that only the code knows about (hard-coded, never stored in session) it should be impossible to reverse.

Comment: If the "token" is request-scoped (which it apparently is) why involve session re-creation for this? Can't a session id be static _throughout the session_ (as it's intended) and have an extra `next_request_token` attribute, which gets updated in every request?

Comment: Also, what happens if I open a second tab in my browser after I login, and copypaste the url from the first one? Will this be a valid request? A new one? A new session? Will I have to login in every tab I open? And if I ebentually succeed, will this invalidate the links/forms in the first tab?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. geomagas, you're right about the 'new tab' issue, it's also a problem if the user hits refresh. The only reason I regenerate the session_id each time is because it was an easy way to get a unique id. I'll work on that a bit more.

Comment: Okay, take 2. Instead of re-generating the session_id at each request, I'll create a token using something like hash('ripemd160', $salt.microtime().$user_id). No one has mentioned any vulnerabilities yet so I'm hoping I'm on the right track as far as security goes.

Comment: 1) You should update your question with your new approach. Not everyone reads all comments to understand the question. 2) Prepend usernames with `@` when answering to comments so we get notified -- I accidentally came back here and had the chance to read your answer 3) Noone will mention _vulnerabilities_ unless you straighten out the _functionality_ issue. Noone checks if a non-functional setup is also vulnerable, it's just _irrelevant_. But you're on the right track, I think you'll pull this off eventually.

Comment: @geomagas Thanks for the advice, this is the first time I've asked anything on stackoverflow. I'm going to update my original post to let people know where I'm at with this.

Answer (score 1):

Inventing your own security algorithms is almost always a bad idea.

> Is this approach safe?

You've not said what it is you are trying to protect aganist - but probably not.

The first issue is that you are adding complexity to you system. Complexity = bugs, bugs undermine security.

What value do you gain by changing the session id for every request? If you're trying to protect against CSRF, then use cookies for the sesion check that the session is valid.

> I thought about adding the request ip address to the db as an additional check

Do you believe that IP address cannot legitimately change mid session? Never heard of load-balancing? Mobile clients?

What happens when the user opens a second window? Or presses the back button?

> $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

You are reducing the entropy by applying the transformations here, not increasing it.